# No route matches [POST] "/locations/new" error when trying to save cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to save a location to a cookie, so I can pass it to google maps.  I don't want to save it to the database since there is no user signed in and there is no need to keep[ the information for later.

I've been trying to do this as both a session and a cookie and I can't seem to get the form to save to the cookie.  I can get an static value to save, but I can't get the value from the form to save.

here is my new.html.erb

```rb
<%= simple_form_for :location do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :location %>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

here is my controller

```rb
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

  def new
    cookies[:location] = params[:location]
  end

  def create
    cookies[:location] = params[:location]
  end

end
```

here is my routes

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :locations
  namespace :admin do
      resources :users
      resources :events

      root to: "users#index"
    end
  resources :events
  resources :locations
  devise_for :users

end
```

I am getting the error: No route matches [POST] "/locations/new"

I can't find a good guide on how to format the new and create areas when it comes to cookies and I've tried a whole bunch of things and I think this is the closest I've gotten to getting it to work.

Edit:  I have attr_accessor :location in my model

Comment: Did you check rake routes?

Comment: I think the way you're using `simple_form_for` needs a resource, like `simple_form_for Location.new`. If you want to leave it as it is then I think you should specify the url and http method like: `simple_form_for :location, url: locations_path, method: :post`.

Comment: I changed it to: 
<%= simple_form_for (:location, url: location_path, method: :post) do |f| %> and now I get the error:
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
=  simple_form_for (:location, url: location_path, method: :
                              ^
C:/Users/Raja/RubymineProjects/tel-aviv-night/app/views/locations/new.html.erb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
          ensure
                ^):

Comment: I did rake routes, you were right, I don't have a POST /locations/new only a GET /locations/new.  I don't know how to fix that though, should I add it to routes and how would I do that?  Should I direct it to GET (how would I do that)?

Comment: what's the `simple_form_for` gem version you're using ?. And not, `new` action should be used with `GET` and not `POST`.

Comment: It is a gem called 'simple_form' that allows you to use a shorter code to make forms.  I've tried it with the standard form_for as well and it does the same thing.  Why is is going to POST and how do I get it to go to GET instead?

Comment: :/ when you use a form, the form usually points to either `create` and `:update` actions, that's why you get that error. The `GET` http method is used for `new` action, and you should not be sending a form to `new` unless you're doing a render after trying to create a resource in your database, in that case it's used to show the errors that might have occurred. With that said, I ask you the same question, I know `simple_form_for` is a gem, what I asked is the gem version.

Comment: btw,  I think you have a type here `simple_form_for (:location, url: location_path, method: :post)`, you used `location_path`, it should be plural according to your routes, like: `simple_form_for :location, url: locations_path, method: :post`

Comment: Apologies, I miss-read.  The version is 4.1.0.  If I don't want to send it through the new action, what do I send it through.  I fixed the typo in locations_path and I get the same error.

Comment: try using `simple_form_for :location, url: locations_path, html: { method: :post }`

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much for being patient with me.  If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.